# Change the way WooCommerce rounds?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using an extension plugin to WooCommerce which lets me customize bulk discount prices.

With that, I need very specific pricings, like $4.23333333333 but the problem is, WooCommerce rounds, I think, two the hundreth, and ignores the rest of the value. Is there a way to change this?

I've tried editing woocommerce.php

```
            define( 'WC_ROUNDING_PRECISION', 4 );
```

And changing the four value to other numbers, but it doesn't seem to change the subtotal/total.

Answer (score 4):

Under WooCommerce > Settings > General, there is an option for number of decimals.

[image: WooCommerce Currency Options]

Also, do not edit WooCommerce core code. Define the constant in your own [site-specific snippets plugin](http://ottopress.com/2011/creating-a-site-specific-snippets-plugin/).

**Edit**

If you only want the option to change in certain places, I think we can filter the `get_option()` value. As a start the following should change the option value when we're on the cart page. But keep in mind that I haven't tested it, so no guarantees.

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_woocommerce_price_num_decimals', 'so_27236553_num_decimals' );
function so_27236553_num_decimals( $value ){
    if( function_exists( 'is_cart' ) && is_cart() ){
        $value = 10;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

This is resulting in the following in the cart:

[image: Cart with a lot of decimals]

You might still need the precision rounding constant you originally pointed out on in your question. I'm not really sure since my price is rounded to the whole dollar.

Comment: That is almost exactly what I needed. The only problem I see though is this affects ALL prices all over the website.. the archies.. product page.. admin product page. All I want it to affect is the values in the cart / review order page. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm doing it wrong, but your 'Edit' didn't work for me. I added that block of code into a functions.php (sub-theme so i'm not editing main WooCommerce files) and I know the functions.php is loading correctly because I have other code that's working. Am I supposed to echo the $pre on the cart page or something?

Comment: Sorry, the `$pre` was a copy-paste fail, but it shouldn't have effected anything. On the cart page I am definitely seeing a lot more zeroes, but it is hard for me to recreate your bulk discount prices, so I don't know if the rounding is happening how you'd like. You might still need the rounding precision constant.